# AWS Cognito "confirmSignUp" is going in error code

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using Cognito login and signup. If I am confirming OTP Code it is giving me an error.

**An error occurred while registering a user AuthError: Username/client id combination not found.
Recovery suggestion: Make sure that the user is present in the backend
Caused by:
userNotFound**

```
func confirmSignUp(for username: String, with confirmationCode: String) {
    _ = Amplify.Auth.confirmSignUp(for: username, confirmationCode: confirmationCode) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(_):
                print("Confirm signUp succeeded")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.checkOTP(otp:self.storeOTP)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("An error occurred while registering a user \(error)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.alert(title: "", message: "OTP not match")
            }
        }
    }
}
```